# RegEx remove parentheses from string

Tags: regex

If I have:

```
string = (1000.00)
```

How can I use regex to remove the parentheses and get the output as `1000.00`?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
s/([()])//g
```

**Brief explanation:**
`[]` is used to create a *character set* for any regular expression. My *character set* for this particular case is composed of `(` and `)`. So overall, substitute `(` and `)` with an empty string.

Comment: That's a little cryptic even for me. Can you explain a bit more for my sake? ;)

Comment: `[]` is used to create a character set. My character set contains `(` and `)`. So overall, substitute `(` and `)` with empty string.

Comment: Ah, that's very minimal. I was a bit puzzled because I was thinking in terms of matched pairs of parentheses.

Comment: Thanks! I used to like this `string.replace(/([()])/g, '')`

Answer (score 9):

Replace the pattern:

```
\((.+?)\)
```

With the replacement pattern:

```
\1
```

Note the escaping of the parentheses `()` for their literal meaning as parenthesis characters.

Comment: i didn't quite understand what the final value would be after replacing. could you pls state this and explain what /1 does? Thanks

Comment: `\1` is a "backreference". It means "whatever was captured by the first set of parentheses."

Comment: so what would the final regex be? sorry to be a pain

Comment: It's a matched pair of the regular expression **match pattern** `\(.+?\)` and the **replacement pattern** `\1`.

Comment: "I don't want to understand it - I just want the answer!"

Comment: @Poldie: heh heh. And I guess "the pattern" is: `s/\(.+?\)/\1/`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Perl syntax: `/\(([0-9\.]+)\)/` (untested)

**UPDATE**: (more strict)

Perl syntax: `/\((-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]*)\)/`

Comment: This will work in this case, but it won't match `(-100.00)`. It also *will* match `(.....)` or `(1.2.3)`. If you're going to be grossly unselective, you might as well do it properly and use `.+?`. ;)

Comment: ok then, Li-aung.. I updated my regex. better? anyway, he didn't strictly ask for numbers, so my regex was perfect for his case..

Comment: Better indeed. The updated one also passes `(1000.)` - a number with a decimal point and no digits after it. *As a sidenote:* for matching a integer or decimal number, I would actually use `(-\s*)?\d+(\.\d+)?`. Add an extra `(\s*[eE]\s*-?\s*\d+)` after that if you want to match engineering notation, like `-1.024e10`. ;)

Comment: And you're right, he didn't ask for numbers. Above comments are for interest only. ;)