# How to create a regex expression on Delphi to remove brackets and quotes

Tags: regex, delphi

I never used TPerlRegEx before and it is my first time for regex expressions.

I am looking for a small example using TPerlRegEx in Delphi Xe2 to remove the brackets and quotes as follows:

input string:

```
["some text"]
```

result:

```
some text
```

single line, no nested brackets or quotes. I have used Regexbuddy to create and test the regex however it is not giving me the result.

Comment: Will those characters always be in the input string? If so, you don't need regular expressions. `s := Copy(s, 3, Length(s) - 4)`

Comment: Here is an example of removing matching `()` pairs, [`RegEx remove brackets from string`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10295743/576719). Change it to remove matching `[]` square brackets and `""` quotes.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, sure I can do that way, but I have not found a regex example with delphi that I could learn like that

Comment: @LU RD: I have tried that. However I could not make the TPerlRegEx give me back only the matched expression. I am missing something, this is why I am looking for a delphi example

Comment: Why don't you use built in regex classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works in Regex Buddy:

Regex:

```
\["(.+?)"\]
```

Replace:

```
$1
```

Use like this:

```
var
  RegEx: TPerlRegEx;
begin
  RegEx := TPerlRegEx.Create(nil);
  try
    Regex.RegEx := '\["(.+?)"\]';
    Regex.Subject := SubjectString;  // ["any text between brackets and quotes"]
    Regex.Replacement := '$1';
    Regex.ReplaceAll;
    Result := Regex.Subject;
  finally
    RegEx.Free;
  end;
end;
```

How it works:

```
Match the character "[" literally «\[»
Match the character """ literally «"»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.+?)»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.+?»
      Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «+?»
Match the character """ literally «"»
Match the character "]" literally «\]»


Created with RegexBuddy
```

Comment: Why is it needed to set Replacement to '$1'?

Comment: @eelias because what is matched with (.+?) pattern i.e. between double quotes becomes a capturing group. You can reference capturing groups by index. In the case of ["some text"] the text <some text> will be captured as group 1. Then he replaces all occurrences of  \["(.+?)"\] with contents of capturing group 1 (i.e. $1) which is <some text> in your case. You can find more info here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Answer (score 2):

[Examples abound](https://www.google.com/search?q=tperlregex+example), including [one in the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE3/en/TPerlRegExReplace_%28Delphi%29), so I assume the question is really about what values to assign to which properties to get the specific desired output.

Set the `RegEx` property to the regular expression that you want to match, and set `Replacement` to the value you want the matched sequences to be replaced with. One way might be to set `RegEx` to `\[|\]|"` and `Replacement` to the empty string. That will remove all brackets and quotation marks from anywhere in the string.

To instead remove just the pairs of brackets and quotation marks that surround the string, try setting `RegEx` to `^\["(.*)"\]$` and `Replacement` to `\1`. That will match the entire string, and then replace it with the first matched subexpression, which excludes the four surrounding characters. To turn a string like `["foo"] ["bar"]` into `foo bar`, then remove the start and end anchors and add a non-greedy qualifier: `\["(.*?)"\]`.

Once you've set up the regular expression and the replacement, then you're ready to assign `Subject` to the string you want to process. Finally, call `ReplaceAll`, and when it's finished, the new string will be in `Subject` again.